# Wordpress post page not working properly

Tags: posts

When I try to create a post, I get the below screen where I can edit. However, the screen I should get is the one in the second image. Please guide me how to solve the issue
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your first screenshot is the block editor. The new editor introduced in WordPress 5.0. It is the default editor, so yes, it is what you "should" get when creating a post.

The second screenshot shows the classic editor, which is often still used for custom post types. If you want to use this editor for Posts (and Pages) you will need to install the [Classic Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/) plugin.

Comment: Thank you so so much. I'm new to all this so was struggling for a long time.